# How to check already running exe in c#.net?

Tags: .net, exe

What is the procedure to know that when Everytime the user starts the application it will check if an instance is already running. If its not running it will launch it otherwise it will focus to the current one.i have already tried the code for singleton application but its giving lots of errors. its not running properly. can u provide me the othr alternative solution for this??

Comment: Scott hanselman has answered here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CommentView.aspx?guid=d2f676ea-025b-4fd6-ae79-80b04a34f24c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `Mutex` class, like explained here: [Best way to implement singleton in a console application C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846637/best-way-to-implement-singleton-in-a-console-application-c/1846651#1846651)

**EDIT:** I have this in my code:

```
class Program
{
    public const string AppName = "...";
    private static readonly Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, Program.AppName);

    public Program()
    {
        if (!mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true))
            throw new ApplicationException("Another instance already running");
    }
}
```

Comment: i have gone through the code of mutex.. but it is giving me errors of public override void dispose(bool disposing); no suitable method found to dispose..this is ocuring on initialize component.. so i have commented that portion.. but major error im facing is on the design view part The designer cannot process the code at line 26: throw new NotImplementedException(); The code within the method 'InitializeComponent' is generated by the designer and should not be manually modified. Please remove any changes and try opening the designer again. i cannot view form.cs[design] plz help me out!

Answer (score 1):

You could used a named [`Mutex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx).

> Named system mutexes are visible
>   throughout the operating system, and
>   can be used to synchronize the
>   activities of processes. You can
>   create a Mutex object that represents
>   a named system mutex by using a
>   constructor that accepts a name.

Comment: thanks for ur answer..
but it is giving me the error for rebuilding my design view again 
its showing me the error on the design view

Comment: i have gone through the code of mutex.. but it is giving me errors
of public override void dispose(bool disposing); no suitable method found to dispose..this is ocuring on initialize component..
so i have commented that portion..
but major error im facing is on the design view part
The designer cannot process the code at line 26: throw new NotImplementedException(); The code within the method 'InitializeComponent' is generated by the designer and should not be manually modified. Please remove any changes and try opening the designer again. 
i cannot view form.cs[design]
plz help me out!

Answer (score 1):

[Single Process Instance Object](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cssingprocess.aspx)

[Creating a Single Instance Application in C#](http://www.iridescence.no/post/CreatingaSingleInstanceApplicationinC.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Using a mutex is not applicable if you're using a background worker.  If the `backgroundWorker` is busy, it can have multiple instances.