# Send event to independent application

Tags: c#, events, console-application, ipc

I am optimizing the parameters of a simulation model that I wrote in C# using an external optimizer.

To allow this external optimizer to 'call' my C# model, I wrote a console application in C# around my model.

The external optimization makes a system call to the console application (the name of this application is an input to the external optimizer).

So far so good.

The problem is that it is not very efficient: every time the console application is called, it needs to initialize my C# model, which takes a lot of time, while in fact I want to run the same model over and over again (thus, initialize it once and then only run it through the console application).

I was thinking about writing another application which initializes my model, keeps running and responds to events raised by the console application (i.e runs the model).

How can I send an event from a console application to a continuously other running  application in C#?

Or shouldn't I do this with events at all and use another way of communication.

Comment: Search term "IPC" ("interprocess communication"). WCF, named pipes, HTTP,...

Answer (score 0):

Named pipes is the simpliest way to organize interprocess communication, it's minimum requirement is `using System.IO.Pipes`

This question has simple example for named pipes usage

[Example of Named Pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806153/example-of-named-pipes)