# Interaction between Windows service and desktop application

Tags: c#, winforms, service

I am developing a project which consists of a Windows service and a Desktop Application in C#.

The job of the Service are
**to monitor a set of Folders for any changes, and log the information to DB** Monitor a set of files and if changed replace with original versions (similar like Windows File Protection)

The Desktop Application is used for

- Displaying the status of Service Function
- In Debug Mode (to display the trace of activities performed by Service)
- Configure Folders and Files

In this context, the major part is interaction between Service and the Desktop Application.

I have 2 choices
1. Remoting
2. WCF

Kindly suggest which is better and effective for my scenario, and how to trace in Debug Mode

Answer (score 1):

I can't recommend any of your two choices, however I do recommend using [Named Pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365590(VS.85).aspx), since this is the way of communication that I use in my Service - Application systems.

Check [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13806752/2126652) for a quick example.

Comment: I want this to be event based, Client will connect to the service only if there is configuration change. But Service will be broadcasting the events, any authorized clients can receive the event data.

Comment: As I searched goggle, i couldn't find a way to fire events from the service that can be captured in the  client. Can some body give a sample on triggering events?