# WPF UI Automation: from Windows Service

Tags: wpf, ui-automation

I have an application which work using UI Automation API with other WPF application.
I have created Windows service which use the same functionality but when the service tries to find the window hwd it receives NULL:

> System.ArgumentException: hwnd cannot be IntPtr.Zero or null.
>          at System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement.FromHandle(IntPtr hwnd)
>          at MyService.Scheduler.GetNotificationWindow(IntPtr hWndtoolBar)

Is it possible to use UI Automation API in Windows Service?

Comment: I dont think this is possible or easy to achieve due to [Session 0 isolation](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2007/04/27/application-compatibility-session-0-isolation/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Windows Service does not have access to the user's desktop. See: [Interaction between Windows service and desktop application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418533/interaction-between-windows-service-and-desktop-application)

So the short answer is: no.

A solution might be to have the service 'talk' to a process on the desktop through a socket and have this process do the automation. (That might lead to getting rid of the service and moving all logic to the desktop app)

Comment: I thought about service only because it starts when OS restarted. May be it is easier to create a small "stupid" service which checks and runs the application if it is not active. And this app uses UIAtomation API and work as now.

Comment: It is even 'easier' to make an application that hides in the system tray and starts with the logging in from the user. That way you do not have a spying application on your machine that tries to spy the desktop of user.