# how to execute second .exe file only after successful execution of first .exe file?

Tags: c#, .net, desktop-application

My doubt is how can i make .exe file(1st .exe for security) such that if secured then execute 2nd .exe file?

Example: i have second.exe file/program(desktop app). i want to make it secure i.e. by asking password or something from user. so i want to create first.exe such that it will check for correct password and all then if success then execute second.exe otherwise not. user should no be able to open second.exe directly. May be this can be done by USB lock or something but don't know how. i am using VB and C#.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use named pipe, first exe acts as a server and it could do a handshake with the second application upon second one is launched, and if only handshake goes through second one can continue

[Example of Named Pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806153/example-of-named-pipes)