# System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000) vs. System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1000).Wait()

Tags: .net, .net-4.5

In learning .NET 4.5, I get the impression that `System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1000).Wait()` (i.e. the blocking delay) is preferred over `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)`.  Is that true, and, if so, why?  Is it simply because the .NET marching orders have always been "use the latest technology whenever possible"?

Comment: Are you sure the first part is `Task.Delay().Wait()`? This will block the thread in the same way that `Sleep` does, only in a more expensive way. Perhaps it was `await Task.Delay()`?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos -- Yes, my question is specifically about the blocking kind of delay (like `Sleep`) where blocking is preferred.  Your allusion to it being more "expensive" is the kind of answer I'm looking for.

Comment: No, you misunderstood. They are just as bad as they do the same bad thing, only Task.Delay.Wait goes through the threadpool to unfreeze the thread. Actually, that T.D.W. evokes a W.T.F. reaction in me. No official or semi-official blog advocates using this construct.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos -- Yeah, I saw it used in the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806153/example-of-named-pipes), which is why I was curious.

Comment: That doesn't mean it's a recommendation. Just that the answerer wanted to add a delay and typed whatever came to mind. You can't execute asynchronously the main method of a console application so any Tasks used there have to be explicitly awaited with a `.Wait()` call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Thread.Sleep(1000)` is preferred because it is the idiomatic way to perform a synchronous wait. It has been the standard for 15 years now. There is nothing wrong with it.

`Task.Delay(1000).Wait()` does the same thing. It is harder to understand, slower to type, slower to execute and, in my mind, backwards thinking.

If you want a synchronous operation call the synchronous API made for that. Sleeping is not special in this regard.