# How can I achieve communication between a windows desktop service and a windows desktop application?

Tags: c#, wcf, service, ipc, desktop-application

I'm writing a windows desktop service that is supposed to download content from a file server on a weekly basis, but it requires users login information to function.

I need the service to be able to "talk back" to the simple tray application I've developed to inform it when things have happened. Things like

Is the users login info good?

Did the content start downloading?

Did the content finish downloading?

I've seen posts on WCF, but, at a glance, WCF feels to me like it's just designed to go around web services. This is going to be a desktop service, not a web service, so unless I'm mistaken in my interpretation, I do not think that WCF is going to work for me? What's my alternative? (or, if I'm mistaken about WCF, can someone point me to a simple tutorial?)

Comment: Did you read my post?  I am working with desktop services. I do not feel that WCF is the correct tool for this job. Did you misunderstand what I said, or did I not say it clearly?

Comment: You could use a message queue (like MSMQ) to send messages back and forth between the Windows service and the desktop app.

Comment: I may have missed it

Comment: @Nelson : Thanks for the direction; I will look into it.

Comment: First read about .NET remoting and then read about WCF .How WCF has replaced .NET remoting. WCF  is not limited to WEB Services

Answer (score 1):

You need to use either a Socket or a NamedPipe. Typically NamedPipe is preferred because it won't trigger some restrictive firewalls that monitor loopback interface as well.

[Example of Named Pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806153/example-of-named-pipes)

Comment: I did decide to go with named pipes. I found something so idiot proof even I shouldn't be able to screw it up http://tech.pro/tutorial/633/interprocess-communication-using-named-pipes-in-csharp.

Answer (score 0):

Write a WCF service and configure a key in the web config(which specifies the user name and password" of the WCF service. Pass the same key from the windows service and authenticate it, once authentication is success, Download the files

eg:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP