# How to handle exception in .net Process() while executing the another console in it

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, console-application

I am executing one .net console from another console App.
Eg MyTool.exe < input.txt

Where Input.txt will have all the input required by tool.

The input in the input file should be dyanmic, so to achive this.

I created another wrapper console App MyWrapper.exe.
This is first crating the input.txt file and then calling the MyTool.exe using .Net Process().

### Content of batch file

MyTool.exe < input.txt

```
var proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "MyBatchFIle.bat";
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.Start();
```

Now here is the question.
Say in case of error or incorrect input, there is possibility that MyTool.exe can go to infinite loop.

So I want to detect this kind of error and stop the execution.

My plan is to execute the MyWrapper.exe from Windows scheduler.

Thanks,
Siraj

Comment: _there is possibility that MyTool.exe can go to infinite loop_ in which world you would not prevent something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You could wait for the process to finish + Timeout. If the process did not finished within the timeout, you can kill it:

```
if(!proc.WaitForExit(timeout))
{ 
    proc.Kill();
}
```

---

Another option is to communicate with the process via [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) (e.g. [named pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806153/example-of-named-pipes)). But that requires the extension of both tools and increases complexity.

---

A third option is to communicate via files. For instance: having a status file that can be written by 'MyTool.exe' in format similar to "[process_ID] status". Then the wrapper could read that infomation periodically and kill the process, restart it or whatever is needed.