# how to send events from console to window form C#

Tags: c#, winforms, console

I have *a Window Form* application in *C#* and another console application which doing some background work.

I run the console application from window form as a process. I want to send some events from console to window form application to be updated what is going on in a console application

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: 1. From your console Application log a text file on the event or action and Windows Application use file watcher to read the same text file and get the changes made in the file. 2. If you have a Database both application and read and write actions.

Comment: I think that post can help you : [Using Named Pipes to communicate between two program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806153/example-of-named-pipes)

Comment: I think you can consider to use old good Win32 API to send message if you let console app know about form app window id (or you can find it by name). If you want just properly integrate console output into your Form app, try to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362111/how-do-i-show-a-console-output-window-in-a-forms-application.

Comment: Search for .NET inter-process communication. For example, take a look at [Local Machine Interprocess Communication with .NET](https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/local-machine-interprocess-communication-with-net).