# Implement " named Pipe"

Tags: python, c#

I want to implement a "named pipe" for exchanging double arrays between a C# and a Python process
does anyone know about that?

I find some code but I can't understand

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: For C#, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806153/example-of-named-pipes

Answer (score -2):

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern unsafe int CreateNamedPipe(
    string lpName, uint dwOpenMode, uint dwPipeMode,
    uint nMaxInstances, int nOutBufferSize,
    int nInBufferSize, int nDefaultTimeOut,
    ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes
    );

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern unsafe int ConnectNamedPipe(
    int hNamedPipe,
    ref OVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
    );

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern unsafe int DisconnectNamedPipe(
    int hNamedPipe
    );

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern unsafe int WriteFile(
    int hFile, void* lpBuffer,
    int nNumberOfBytesToWrite,
    int* lpNumberOfBytesWritten,
    ref OVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
    );

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern unsafe int ReadFile(
    int hFile, void* lpBuffer,
    int nNumberOfBytesToRead,
    int* lpNumberOfBytesRead,
    ref OVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
    );

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern unsafe int CloseHandle(
    int hObject
    );
```

A:

This method is for communicating with a separate process using a Windows named pipe.  If you want to communicate between two threads in the same process (or between two processes on the same machine), you would use a `MemoryMappedFile` or `P/Invoke` `CreateFileMapping` and `MapViewOfFile`.

Comment: There's a whole namespace `System.IO.Pipes` that deals with named pipes in the .net framework, so there's no need to use p/invoke from C# for that purpose